# Need route(s) for sewing CXF to ActiveMQ by using Camel

Tags: xml, apache-camel, cxf

To understand how should I configure `camel` routes for `cxf-jms` binding I'm testing various methods in [this cxf-soap example](http://briansjavablog.blogspot.com/2016/10/apache-cxf-contract-first-web-service.html) but haven't yet succeed :(

I want soap requests that are received from clients to be stored in a activemq queue (request queue) and then being dispatched to the server. Then responses from server should be at first stored in another queue (response queue) and then to be delivered to the clients as follows:

```
(client) soap request <-> activeMQ queue <-> soap responses (server)
```

I want to know how should I add camel `context`, `routes`, `endpoints`, etc in the following spring config file to get camel working for me as I've described above.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
 xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
 xmlns:jaxws="http://cxf.apache.org/jaxws"
 xsi:schemaLocation="
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://cxf.apache.org/jaxws http://cxf.apache.org/schemas/jaxws.xsd">


 <context:component-scan base-package="com.briansjavablog.accounts" />

 <jaxws:server id="accountService"
        address="http://localhost:8080/apache-cxf-demo/services/accounts">
     <jaxws:serviceBean>
  <bean class="com.briansjavablog.accounts.service.AccountServiceEndpoint" />
     </jaxws:serviceBean>
     <jaxws:inInterceptors>
  <ref bean="loggingInInterceptor" />
     </jaxws:inInterceptors>
     <jaxws:outInterceptors>
                <ref bean="loggingOutInterceptor" />
     </jaxws:outInterceptors>
 </jaxws:server>

 <jaxws:client id="testAccountServiceClient"
        address="http://localhost:8080/apache-cxf-demo/services/accounts"
        serviceClass="com.briansjavablog.accounts.Accounts">
     <jaxws:inInterceptors>
         <ref bean="loggingInInterceptor" />
     </jaxws:inInterceptors>
     <jaxws:outInterceptors>
                <ref bean="loggingOutInterceptor" />
     </jaxws:outInterceptors>
 </jaxws:client>

 <bean id="abstractLoggingInterceptor" abstract="true">
     <property name="prettyLogging" value="true" />
 </bean>
 <bean id="loggingInInterceptor" class="org.apache.cxf.interceptor.LoggingInInterceptor" parent="abstractLoggingInterceptor" />
 <bean id="loggingOutInterceptor" class="org.apache.cxf.interceptor.LoggingOutInterceptor" parent="abstractLoggingInterceptor" />

</beans>
```

I've seen some examples, read some tutorials, tried a lot but couldn't solve the problem :(

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Where are your Camel context and route?

Comment: What SOAP webservice specific processing are you doing before enqueuing the request or before forwarding the response to the client? When you say you want to forward the SOAP request itself, that sounds like you don't need a WS endpoint. You could simply provide an HTTP endpoint, no need to deal with the CXF configuration complexity.